# Do I need to test my app on instruments?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I finish building my app and I don't see any error on xCode 4.2! Do I need to test it on the Instruments before send it to appStore?

Comment: Why the downvote? I felt the question was genuine enough for a starter.

Comment: Pre-release checklist: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480044/pre-release-checklist-before-building-final-version-for-app-store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't NEED to test your app although it would be nice for your users, instruments will let you see the performance of your app and also whether or not you have memory leakages.

Give it a go if you can [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend you to test your app on a real device before submitting it to the Apple Store because in various situations (depending on the size and complexity of your app) there are some errors or warnings that don't appear on the simulator but do appear on the real device. An example on this is the Media Player ([this post is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218336/mpmovieplayercontroller-causing-a-mp-playbackinterruptiondidendnotification-on)).

Another important reason is that the simulator does not support all real device situations. For example you can not receive Text Messages (SMS) or incoming calls on the simulator, and it is important that you test your app for such situations (handle states of `appWillResignActive`, `appDidBecomeActive`...).

And as our friends noted above, it would be nice for you to see your app in the way your customers will see it before you sell it to them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not mandatory, but I'd recommend it - particularly if you were an indie developer looking to start making your mark on the Appstore.

Any warnings that Xcode presents are also acceptable - but anything serious that occurs during runtime and through the things Apple will do to it during the submission process will be flagged to you; you'll even get a crash log. (again, as a rule of thumb I'd recommend clearing warnings where possible - and given any time restraints on the project)

Just remember that no matter how much testing Apple will do - their systems can and DO miss things, like specific configs or situations on iDevices that just happen. (just because iDevices are very less fragmented in comparison to say Android, things always occur!)

Hope this helps - good luck!

Also, you might find this useful:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Instruments is for performance analysis and is not necessarily a "part" of your app building process. It would be nice for you to do some profiling for your app using this tool so that you, as the developer, give the best UX to the end user.