# making app compatible with previous iOS versions

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, compatibility

I just released my app but I am only able to make it compatible from 4.3 and up.
When I try to go any lower than 4.3 (xcode), it says I need to add code to make this work.
Does anyone know how to do this or has any suggestions? I would like my app to be compatible with 3.0 and onwards.

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you already published on the AppStore?

Comment: make sure you change version in Deployment Target, Build Settings, and Under Info for both targets and project. Also be sure that you have armv6 and armv7 set as well.

Comment: Verbatim error messages are helpful, can you post whatever Xcode spits out?

Comment: @AmitApollo That is exactly my issue, what is armv6 and armv7? How do I set it? Thanks

Comment: @RazorSharp Yes I have already been published on the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checklist:

In your project's build settings…

- Did you set the "iOS Deployment Target" to iOS 3?
- Did you include the `armv6` architecture in both, the built and the valid architectures?

In general:

- Do you link to any framework that is not supported on iOS 3?
- Do you use any methods, classes or other features that have been added later?

Comment: How do you include armv6 and armv7? I believe this is my issue. Thanks!

Comment: In Xcode, look for "Architectures" and "Valid Architectures" in the project's build settings. If the lists do not include "armv6", edit them accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You have to reach the least common code, what I mean by this is that you must find all the methods that are all incompatible within all of these versions of the OS. After that you will have to find each and every of it's functional equivalents. Then you can use conditional statements to check for every version and see what fits better or you can use the `respondsToSelector` method inherited from the `NSObject` class. In the end you have to test it on each device you are targeting :P

You can run this [checkup list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480044/pre-release-checklist-before-building-final-version-for-app-store) that I have always liked.

Edit:

I think I misunderstood your question though it has already been mentioned, be sure to check your deployment target in your build settings.