# Is there a (maybe official) checklist and guide for submitting an app to the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, universal-binary

I submitted one almost 2 years ago and remember next to nothing. Just that it was very hard and that about a gazillion things had to be considered.

Now we have a universal iPhone / iPad binary.

Maybe someone can point out some resources which give a good and quick overview of what has to be checked / done?

Some things that come to mind for a useful checklist:

- Make sure NSZombiesEnabled is NO
- ... what else?

Comment: If you have a developer account, read the App Store Review Guidelines.

Comment: Not official but this is like my favorite list for [doing this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480044/pre-release-checklist-before-building-final-version-for-app-store

Comment: To the dude voted for close: So in case someone thinks this is not programming related. WRONG! It has to do with getting a distribution build right, and that's very damn programming related IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

https://ontestpad.com/library/201/ios-app-store-submission-checklist

Answer (score 0):

Another important thing that hasn't been mentioned is that `Xcode 4` can perform some validation to your Application before submitting it to the App Store.

After you have archived the App, you can go to Xcode's Organizer and "Validate" the App. That can save you a lot of valuable time.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Check this blog post, it was useful for me: [blogpost](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2015/01/13/ios-checklists-creating-and-submitting-your-app/)

It contains very detailed lists for submitting apps, and also for starting a new app.

It contains such a useful points:

> In the “Edit Scheme” section of Xcode, “Archive” should be set to
>   “Release”. Release builds must hide log statements and turn off any
>   test code/test screens used for development.
>
> NOTE: Due to compiler optimizations, release builds can sometimes
>   function differently than debug builds. It is best to start testing
>   release builds a few days before the release to the App Store in order
>   to capture any possible issues.
>   Make sure the app is communicating with the correct production servers
>   (using HTTPS).
>
> Make sure all test screens are hidden.
>
> Make sure no sensitive data is printed to the console.
>
> Make sure Analytics is working with the correct production account.
>
> Make sure services such as Urban Airship are working with the correct
>   production account.

Also I found other useful [link](https://medium.com/@stanfy/check-list-submit-to-appstore-b0a56f42275a#.2wvfzpt21)  now:

APNS

> Make sure that APNS certificate includes your app’s BundleID.
>
> You have created distribution APNS certificate.
>
> Your server is using distribution APNS certificate.
>
> Check that notifications are working on different iOS versions (pay
>   attention to iOS8 where API was changed).     Versioning
>
> Do not hardcode anywhere in sources things like isBeta=YES or
>   DEBUG=YES.
>
> Make sure that the app icon or name doesn’t contain “beta” word.
>
> Update app version and build version. Never hardcode version inside
>   app (use CFBundleVersion instead).
>
> IMPORTANT Make sure that the new release is installed over the old
>   version in the correct way:
>
> ** Install app from AppStore. Create ad-hoc build and install it over the old version.
>
> ** Check that data from NSUserDefaults is read in the correct way (app doesn’t crash trying to read non-existing keys).
>
> ** Check that user doesn’t lose any of his info after update.