# PhoneGap appstore submission

Tags: iphone, cordova, app-store

"We are developing an application using phonegap1.2 , let us know if such applications are accepted by app store"  .If not please give suggestions to submit to Apple's appstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is accepted. no problems for it. there were problems reported for earlier versions of phonegap, before 1.0  that was fixed, and after that there has been no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Our company submitted a PhoneGap 1.0 based application last year without any problems.  As long as you follow some of the general application guidelines you should not have any problems getting your application on the app store.

Here are some the the key points we used.

- Application does not crash, or produce exceptions
- If a data connection is required you notify the user and handle loss of data.
- Your app does not contain objectionable content.

Another good resource is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1480044/181776) regarding a appstore checklist, not everything will apply when using PhoneGap but it is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have finish your application. If not, beginning on May 1 2013, all PhoneGap Build iOS apps submitted to the Apple App store must be built with PhoneGap 2.5.0 or above.

[Phonegap blog](http://phonegap.com/blog/build/new-apple-app-store-submittal-rules/)